# $\theta$-characteristics and Heisenberg action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complete smooth curve over $\mathbb C$ and $A=Jac[2]$ be the group of 2-torsion elements in the Jacobian of $X$. Is their a relation between:

1) The $A$-torsor of $\theta$-characteristics and its decomposition into odd and even parts.

2) The projective action of $A$ on sections of ${\mathcal O}_{Jac}(2\Theta)$, where $\Theta$ is the $\Theta$-divisor, lifting to a Heisenberg group action.